# Find div without class (web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to find a div without any class like in below example the div has a class

```
authordiv = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'list-authors'})
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You want to find all divs without classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find divs without class, try this:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': None})
```

If your problem is to find any div (with or without class), just remove the second argument

Answer (score 1):

Use *None* object as a class name:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': None})
```

Comment: @JBernardo answered 46 secs ago